# Blender Stack Exchange in languages other than English?

Tags: discussion, support

Are there versions of Stack Exchange generally, or Blender Stack Exchange in particular, in languages other than English? If not, where can one direct a user who is hampered by trying to ask a question in English, when English is not a language in which they are particularly facile? Should there be an entry on the resources question that points to help resources in other languages.

Comment: I think there isn't; if taking into account StackExchange format then this could be made the same as with StackOverflow which now is in Portuguese, Spanish, Russian except for the main one. As such a proper proposal should be made for that.